# pyqt5 porting error while connecting actions to methods: AttributeError: type object 'QObject' has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python-3.5, pyqt5

I know this is a typical pyqt4 to pyqt5 porting problem but so far existing questions did not help me to see a solution to my current problem: Could I get a push?

Here is the class generating the following error

```
AttributeError: type object 'QObject' has no attribute 'connect'
```

the class

```
import logging
import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from gui.gui import Ui_MainWindow

from lib import bcinetwork
from lib import bcixml

triggered = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
NORMAL_COLOR = QtCore.Qt.black
MODIFIED_COLOR = QtCore.Qt.gray

#class BciGui(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
class BciGui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, protocol='bcixml'):
        #QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.protocol = protocol

        self.model = TableModel(self)
        self.proxymodel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxymodel.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.proxymodel.setFilterKeyColumn(- 1)
        self.proxymodel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.proxymodel)
        self.tableView.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableView.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)




    self.toolButton_clearFilter.setDefaultAction(self.actionClearFilter)

    self.comboBox_feedback = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.toolBar)

    self.comboBox_feedback.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                         QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    self.toolBar.insertWidget(self.actionSendInit, self.comboBox_feedback)



        # connect actions to methods
        #QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionOpen, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.clicked)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionChangeFeedbackController, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.changeFeedbackController)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionClearFilter, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.clearFilter)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionOpen, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.open)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionPause, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.pause)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionPlay, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.play)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionQuit, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.quit)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionStop, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.stop)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionSave, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.save)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionSaveAs, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.saveas)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionSendModified, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.sendModified)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionSendAll, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.sendAll)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionSendInit, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.sendinit)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionGet, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.get)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged(const QString&)"), self.filter)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.model, QtCore.SIGNAL("dataChanged(const QModelIndex&, const QModelIndex&)"), self.dataChanged)

        self.feedbacks = []

        self.setFeedbackController(bcinetwork.LOCALHOST, bcinetwork.FC_PORT)
```

It comes down when generally connecting actions to methods here

```
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionChangeFeedbackController, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.changeFeedbackController)
```

this gets me the mentionned error

```
AttributeError: type object 'QObject' has no attribute 'connect'
```

I understand this part of the code is a typical Pyqt4 problem which does not work anymore in Pyqt5. So I saw many explanations of new signals for specific widgets but I fail to see a solution for an action in general. Can someone give me an explanation ?

thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I think I got it working by doing the following:

```
#QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionChangeFeedbackController, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.changeFeedbackController)
 self.actionChangeFeedbackController.triggered.connect(self.changeFeedbackController)
```